Visual Studio doesn't work properly with Clumsy
I use Clumsy 0.3 to emulate network problems and test my application. Clumsy is configured  shown in the screenshot below:

Then I run application through a Visual Studio 2022 debugging session and it runs very slowly. For example, finding the source is quite long (but not endless). And it finishes immediately after Clumsy stops.

How to prevent Visual Studio from lagging? Which port should be outside the Clumsy filter? Or is there an option like processId?
I found out list of ports, which VS uses while remote debugging, and filter it (tcp.DstPort != 4026 and tcp.SrcPort != 4026), but it appears to be ineffective.
